# find repeated words in string and symbols between them

Tags: c, string

I need to find 2 similar words in one sentence and i need to find how much symbols are between these two words. I can't figure out the alghoritm.

For example sentence would be-

> This is nice table and nice chair.

Similar words are- `nice`

Symbols between them are 11 or 8(dont know if space is count as symbol)

```
int main()    
char text[200];
printf("Enter one sentence \n ");
gets(text);
```

Maybe first of all would be

```
dist=strtok(text, " ,.!?");
while(dist!=0)
{
 printf("%s\n", dist);
 dist=strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
 }
```

and it wil output each word and maybe then can search for similar words if there would be 2 strings then i would use strstr but i dont know how to do with one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `toupper` or `tolower` to make the whole string upper/lower case. This will make subsequent comparisons easier.
2. Using `strtok`, create an array of `char*` values that point to the start of each word in the sentence. You can eliminate empty strings and punctuation at this stage, if you like.
3. Use a nested loop to compare each pair of words in this array using the `strcmp` function.
4. When two words match, you can calculate the distance between them by using pointer arithmetic and the `strlen` function.

Comment: Ok i will  use strtok first like this


    char *word = strtok(text, " ");


And then compare it with input text like this?


     if( strcmp(word,text) == 0 )

          printf("equal is.\n");

       else

          printf("no words are equal.\n");

Comment: No, because then you would only be comparing with the first word each time. Create an array of char pointers (`char* words[200];`, or whatever). Call `strtok` repeatedly, and put the return values into this array (`words[0]`, `words[1]`, etc.). Stop when `strtok` returns NULL. Then use a nested loop to compare these words: `for (i=0; i<nwords-1; i++) for (j=i+1; j<nwords; j++) { if (strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0) /* match found */ ... }`

Comment: Can you please give code example how to put return values into array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

+create an array of string, e.g `words[50][20]` or you can use dynamic memory allocation if you are familiar with it.

+Copy each character of your text[] into words[0] until it reaches the white space. Jump to words[1], and so on until the end of text[] is met.

+Now what you just need to do is strcmp all words to find identical strings. In your above example, you should get `strcmp(words[2],words[5])=0`

+To find how many symbols between them, just sum up the length of all words between them, e.g `strlen(words[3])+strlen(words[4])` in your example. If you want to take white space into account, add 1 to the total sum for each words

It is the algorithm. You should implement the code yourself

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would be something like this:

1. Using strtok (or manual parsing if you like, strtok is thread unsafe), get all the words in the sentence.
2. At each step, insert the word in a map (hashtable) where the key is the word itself and the value is the position where it starts in the sentence and the value is stored in an array.
3. After you finish parsing the input, you will end up with a map having the keys as the words and the values as sorted arrays of starting positions in the original sentence.
4. Now, All you have to do to get the number of characters is to subtract any 2 consecutive positions in an array corresponding to a word, given that this array has more than 2 elements, thus the word appears in the sentence more than once. Example: Suppose "nice" appears on pos 10 and on pos 20, you will have these 2 in the array of positions in the map => you can calculate the distance

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you are going to use the result for. Is it for modifying a string, printing stats, copy out words, etc. Does it have to be thread safe, should it support constant strings etc. What is most important of efficiency and simplicity.

One approach is to rely on pointers in entirety.

1. Pointer to first word, `ptr1`.
2. Pointer to next word, `ptr2`.

   1. Check word `ptr1` against word `ptr2`.
   2. Advance `ptr2` to next word.
   3. If match not found, Goto 1.
3. If match not found, advance `ptr2` to next word.
4. Goto 2.

A bare skeleton for comparing words could be something like this:

```
int compare_word(char *word1, char *word2)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0;
                word1[i] && word2[i] &&
                word1[i] == word2[i] &&
                isalpha(word1[i]); ++i)
                ;

        return i && !isalpha(word1[i]) && !isalpha(word2[i]);
}
```

---

One thing to remember when calculating distance between words is to be aware of multi byte string formats such as utf-8. One *letter* can be several bytes:

```
a æøå a
 ^---^ 8 bytes, 5 characters.
```

You can use `mbstowcs` to get length of a multibyte sequence, but then you also have to take heed to locale. A typical scenario:

```
char *test = "æøå";

printf("%s: %u\n", test, mbstowcs(NULL, test, 0));
printf("%s: %u\n", test, strlen(test));

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

puts("-----------------------------------------------");
printf("%s: %u\n", test, mbstowcs(NULL, test, 0));
printf("%s: %u\n", test, strlen(test));
```

Result:

```
æøå: 4294967295
æøå: 6
-----------------------------------------------
æøå: 3
æøå: 6
```

Anyhow. As a sample of concept here is some lines of code. Note that this one is not byte-safe – (only ASCII gives sane results). Numbers at end of stippled lines are *"distance: start of word 1 to start of word 2"*, *"distance end of word 1 to start of word 2"* and *"word width"*. Example output:

```
$ ./wordword 
Enter one sentence:
Lizzie Borden took an axe And gave her mother forty whacks When she saw what she had done She gave her father forty-one.

Lizzie Borden took an axe And gave her mother forty whacks When she saw what she had done She gave her father forty-one.
                              ^---------------------------------------------------------------^ (64, 60, 4)
MATCH: 'gave' 60 bytes of separation.  (Press enter for next.)

Lizzie Borden took an axe And ____ her mother forty whacks When she saw what she had done She ____ her father forty-one.
                                   ^---------------------------------------------------------------^ (64, 61, 3)
MATCH: 'her' 61 bytes of separation.  (Press enter for next.)

Lizzie Borden took an axe And ____ ___ mother forty whacks When she saw what she had done She ____ ___ father forty-one.
                                              ^---------------------------------------------------------------^ (64, 59, 5)
MATCH: 'forty' 59 bytes of separation.  (Press enter for next.)

Lizzie Borden took an axe And ____ ___ mother _____ whacks When she saw what she had done She ____ ___ father _____-one.
                                                                ^------------^ (13, 10, 3)
MATCH: 'she' 10 bytes of separation.  (Press enter for next.)
```

Sample code. (OK, went a bit overboard in *completeness* here. Started out with 30 lines and grew a bit to much. But still, it has quite a few shortcomings and is only meant as an example by use of pointers etc.):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define FMT_BBLACK     "\033[1;30m"                /* Bold color black */
#define FMT_BRED       "\033[1;31m"                /* Bold color red */
#define FMT_BGREEN     "\033[1;32m"                /* Bold color green */
#define FMT_BYELLOW    "\033[1;33m"                /* Bold color yellow */
#define FMT_BBLUE      "\033[1;34m"                /* Bold color blue */
#define FMT_BMAGENTA   "\033[1;35m"                /* Bold color magenta */
#define FMT_BCYAN      "\033[1;36m"                /* Bold color cyan */
#define FMT_BWHITE     "\033[1;37m"                /* Bold color white */
#define FMT_NONE       "\033[0m"                   /* Reset */
#define FMT_MATCH      FMT_BRED

#define DEL_NONE       0x00                        /* Keep words. (Causes re-match) */
#define DEL_WORD1      0x01                        /* Remove first word-match */
#define DEL_WORD2      0x02                        /* Remove second word-match */
#define DEL_BOTH       (DEL_WORD1 | DEL_WORD2)

/* Print graph */
int debug = 1;

/* ********************************************************************** *
 *        Helper functions
 * ********************************************************************** */
/* Return pointer to next alpha,
 * or null on end of string) */
char *skip_noword(char *p)
{
        while (*p && !isalpha(*p))
                ++p;
        return p;
}

/* Return pointer to byte after last alpha,
 * or null on end of C-string */
char *eof_word(char *p)
{
        while (*p && isalpha(*p))
                ++p;
        return p;
}

/* Return pointer to first letter of next word,
 * or null on end of C-string. */
char *next_word(char *p)
{
        p = eof_word(p);
        return skip_noword(p);
}

/* Compare whole word starting at p1 with word starting at p2.
 * Return 1 on match, else 0.
 * */
int compare_word(char *p1, char *p2)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0;
                p1[i] && p2[i] &&
                isalpha(p1[i]) &&
                p1[i] == p2[i]; ++i)
                ;

        return i && !isalpha(p1[i]) && !isalpha(p2[i]);
}

/* ********************************************************************** *
 *        Search routine
 * ********************************************************************** */
/* Find next word with a matching entry.
 * Return pointer to first word.
 * Set match to matching entry.
 * */
char *word_word(char *buf, char **match)
{
        char *p;
        *match = NULL;

        buf = skip_noword(buf);

        /* Outer loop.
         * Advance one and one word. */
        while (*buf) {
                /* Inner loop.
                 * Compare current buf word with rest of words after it. */
                p = next_word(buf);
                while (*p) {
                        if (compare_word(buf, p)) {
                                *match = p;
                                return buf;
                        }
                        p = next_word(p);
                }
                buf = next_word(buf);
        }

        return (char*)NULL;
}

/* ********************************************************************** *
 *        Clear, Copy, Print etc.
 * ********************************************************************** */

/* Bytes between end of one word to beginning of next.
 * */
size_t words_dist(char *w1, char *w2)
{
        return w2 - eof_word(w1);
}

/* Replace all alpha characters with given char.
 * */
void clear_word(char *p, char r)
{
        while (*p && isalpha(*p))
                *p++ = r;
}

/* Return a copy of word pointed to by p.
 * */
void *word_cpy(char *p)
{
        void *buf;
        char *start = p;
        size_t n;

        n = eof_word(p) - start + 1;
        if (!(buf = malloc(n)))
                return (void*)NULL;
        memcpy(buf, start, n);
        ((char*)buf)[n - 1] = 0x00;

        return buf;
}

/* Print graph showing position of p2 and p3 in p1.
 * */
void explain(char *p1, char *p2, char *p3)
{
        size_t n1 = p3 - p2;
        size_t n2 = words_dist(p2, p3);

        puts(p1);
        while (p1++ != p2)
                putchar(' ');
        putchar('^');
        while (++p2 != p3)
                putchar('-');
        printf("^ (%d, %d, %d)\n", n1, n2, n1 - n2);
}

/* Print C-string using color.
 *
 * */
void print_word(FILE *out, char *word)
{
        fprintf(out, "%s%s%s", FMT_MATCH, word, FMT_NONE);
}

/* Print single word pointed to by p in (longer) C-string.
 * Use dynamic buffer.
 * */
void print_word_safe(FILE *out, char *p)
{
        char *word;

        if (!(word = word_cpy(p)))
                return;
        print_word(out, word);
        free(word);
}

/* Print single word pointed to by p in (longer) C-string.
 * Modify and reset source.
 * */
void print_word_mod(FILE *out, char *p)
{
        char *start = p;
        char csave;

        p = eof_word(p);
        csave = *p;
        *p = 0x00;
        print_word(out, start);
        *p = csave;
}

/* ********************************************************************** *
 *        Main
 * ********************************************************************** */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char buf_scan[4096];    /* Buffer holding typed input. */
        char *buf_start;        /* Start of buffer. */
        char *buf_pos;          /* Current position in buffer. */
        char *match;            /* Position for matched word. */
        int delete;             /* Delete flag mask. */

        debug = 1;              /* 1=Print explanation. */
        delete = DEL_BOTH;      /* DEL_[NONE, WORD1, WORD2, BOTH] */

        if (argc > 1) {
                /* Use first argument instead of user input. */
                buf_start = argv[1];
        } else {
                /* Get user input. */
                buf_start = buf_scan;
                fputs("Enter one sentence:\n", stderr);
                if (!fgets(buf_scan, sizeof(buf_scan) - 1, stdin))
                        buf_scan[0] = 0x00;
                buf_scan[strlen(buf_scan) - 1] = 0x00;
                putc('\n', stderr);
        }

        buf_pos = buf_start;
        /* Get next matching pair. */
        while ((buf_pos = word_word(buf_pos, &match))) {
                if (debug)
                        explain(buf_start, buf_pos, match);
                /* Report findings */
                fputs("MATCH: ", stderr);
                print_word_mod(stderr, buf_pos);
                fprintf(stderr,
                        " %d bytes of separation.",
                        words_dist(buf_pos, match)
                );
                /* Clear out matched word pair. */
                if (delete & DEL_WORD1) {
                        clear_word(buf_pos, '_');
                }
                if (delete & DEL_WORD2) {
                        clear_word(match, '_');
                }
                /* Advance head to next word. */
                buf_pos = next_word(buf_pos);
                fputs("  (Press enter for next.)", stderr);
                getchar();
                putc('\n', stderr);
        }

        if (0 && debug)
                printf("FINE:\n%s\n\n", buf_start);

        return 0;
}
```